# Using Structures with Web Services

Tags: vb.net, web-services, arguments

I have a web service it looks like this,

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Function AcceptTest(ByVal j As jidh) As Integer

    MsgBox(j.age + " " + j.name)
   // Some insert preocedure and calculations in Server
    Return 110
End Function
```

My Structure is ,

```
Public Structure jidh
    Public name As String
    Public age As Integer
End Structure
```

Can anyone please tell me the syntax  that, how could I consume this web service from my front-end client application.

I am unable to pass a structure which is having 20 to 30 data in it to the web service.

Comment: There are a few things odd here - Web apps and windows forms message boxes shouldnt be mixed. As for structures, you should just use Class instead, unless you have some incredibly necessary reason to use a struct instead. There are also public variables in the struct, and a struct shouldnt be mutable.

Comment: Simply putting a "WebMethod" attribute on a class method does not make a web service. That code needs to be hosted in IIS as a web application - if you have it in a windows forms or WPF application, you are missing a fundamental concept.